# Auto create has_many :through record without session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure out how to automatically create a has_many through record without an active session.

I have two models related through a family_association model:

```
class Tree < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :family_associations
has_many :families, through: :family_associations
end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :family_associations
has_many :trees, through: :family_associations
end
```

On my Show Tree view there is a button to create a new Family and passes the Tree's id as a url parameter

```
<%= link_to "Add Family to Tree", new_family_path(:tree_id=>@tree.id), :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

FYI: I can't have a Family belongs_to Tree model because in theory a family my elect to belong to more than one tree in the future. So there is no tree_id field to pre-populate on the new Family form.

The goal is to create the Family Association record after the Family record has saved. So far I have created the associate_family helper method:

```
 def associate_family(tree, family)
    FamilyAssociation.create(:tree_id => tree, :family_id => family)
 end
```

And included the following logic in my Family controller's Create method:

```
    if @family.save
       associate_family(params[:tree_id], @family.id)
```

The association record is created but not surprisingly, the tree_id is missing. Am I going about this the right way? Is there any way to temporarily carry the tree_id url parameter from New to Create?

Answer (score 1):

According to your models, I think you are trying to make a tree of families. If that is the case then I suggest you to use [Ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) and for more information you can see its [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry).

If you want to stick through has_many :through association and want to pass it temporarily from new to create, I have done the way you have done. I don't know other options too.